# Duplicate Home Indicator Look

Tags: ios, colors

Is it possible to duplicate the home indicator look? Specifically, the color of the home indicator changes depending on the color of whatever is behind it so that it is always visible. Is there a public method that can be used to duplicate this behavior? My use case is to show a boundary lines matching a polygon selected by the user over an image, so to make it visible for all images, it would be great if it could be a different color than the image. The trick is that it will vary unpredictably by image.

Comment: A lot of it is done with private frameworks, but there's a really detailed analysis here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reverse-engineering-the-iphone-x-home-indicator-color-a4c112f84d34/

Comment: Thanks for that link. It went into some detail about stuff I already knew. I figured it was probably done with a private framework, but I can always hope. As a side note, I hate this indicator. I don't have one on my iPhone 7 Plus, obviously, but I do have one on my iPad Pro, and I never use it. I also notice that it disappears in some of Apple's own screens, so they apparently don't think it's needed either even though they force it on us. :(

Comment: I may try something with `CIFilter`, perhaps `CIColorCrossPolynomial` or `CIColorCube`.